# SQL Server JDBC connection Login fails using Property File Reader

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jmeter

**Issue** :SQL Server JDBC connection Login fails using Property File Reader.

When i pass hard corded values for it's working, but when i used Property File Reader throws login error.

For db2 it's perfectly working.

I was not sure where was wrong,please advise me.

See the below screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: I have figured it out what and where went wrong.Please remove -1

Comment: why not write the answer instead ? it would help others facing the same issue and you would contribute. Accept your answer after few days.

Comment: I have passed incorrect username variable.Instead of ${__P(db_user2,)} i have passed ${__P(db_username,)}

Comment: So just write this in an answer. And then accept it. thx

Comment: Where do I need to click for the accept.I didn't see option.

Comment: I did it. when i clicked on accept it's saying I have to accept it after 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have passed incorrect username variable.

Instead of `${__P(db_user2,)}` i have passed `${__P(db_username,)}`